# What does #0 mean in bash?

Tags: bash

I try to understand this bash code :

```
$ var=00.00
$ echo ${var#0}
0.00
```

It seems that `#0` can be used to truncate the end of var but I never saw this notation in bash documentation : https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

Anybody can tell me what `#0` is exactly ?

Thx!

Comment: It's the same as any `${var#pattern}`; there's nothing special about `0`

Comment: See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe. Note that it's trimming the _beginning_, not the end; trimming the end would be `${var%pattern}` instead.

Comment: BTW, it **is** in the documentation; in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion, see `${parameter#word}`

Comment: Thx! I didn't manage to find it.